# Can Console Refresh All Subtabs Trigger Visualforce Page Tabs to Be Refreshed?

Tags: visualforce, console

Can the following out of box subtabs 'Refresh all subtabs' link in image below trigger visualforce sub tabs in the console to be refreshed? At the moment its only refreshing standard sub tabs.

[image]

Comment: I'd expect it to depend on your code if they're custom tabs.